# Accessing SQL database from within IDE (VS2010) thru Firewall

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, vpn

Is is possible to grant VS2010 access to a SQL database via a VPN? The resulting program(exe) works welll after entering the programname into the list of programs of the firewall. I do not know waht name to enter to let the VS2010 also thru the firewall.

Any suggestions?

Greetings,
Steven

Comment: Did you try using Port numbers in Windows Firewall instead of program names? http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Open-a-port-in-Windows-Firewall

Comment: Yes, i just did. I entered port 1433 (In and Out) but no change. SQL Management Studio has no problems whatsover. I'm stuck

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the `<yourapp`>.vshost.exe from the Bin\Debug folder to the exceptionlist of Windows Firewall.